# Nsight Debug %1 is no a valid Win32 application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, cuda, gpu, nsight

I have a `VS 2010` project where I have a `.cu` file that adds two vectors. It is the one from cuda sdk 5.5 samples. Also, I have replaced the main function with a mexfunction and made the correct changes in order to run the function via matlab and works fine. Then I tried to run the *CUDA Debugging* but did not start. It returns the following error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Win 7 64x, VS 2010, CUDA SDK 5.5 64x, Nsight 3.1 64x, the project in visual studio is 64x build, GForce 9600.

Comment: For those who have already read the question the answer is because the output is a .mexw64 file which can not be debugged explicitly neither with classic cpu nor with gpu debug. You must attach matlab in visual studio and then the debug will work. Unfortunately, this is an other problem I am encountering when working with gpu debug and described in one of my posts. (Probably I will delete this false alarm post.)

Comment: add this comment as an answer (which is perfectly OK here). Later you can accept the answer, which will leave the answered question behind for the next person with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have already read the question the answer is because the output is a .mexw64 file which can not be debugged explicitly neither with classic cpu nor with gpu debug. You must attach matlab in visual studio and then the debug will work. Unfortunately, this is an other problem I am encountering when working with gpu debug and described in one of my posts.